# Add only a percentage of rows to DataTable

Tags: c#, random, datatable

So i'm making a program to Audit some of our workers randomly. And i'm trying to make a program to scan our Access DB and pull a percentage of orders. But i want to randomly select the orders, i dont want just the top 5% or something.

```
static DataTable RandomSelect(double errPercentage,string User)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);
        string query = "SELECT ControlNumber FROM Log WHERE User ='" + User + "' AND Log.EndStatus in ('Needs Review', 'Check Search', 'Vision Delivery', 'CA Review', '1TSI To Be Delivered');";


        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtRandomRows = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);


            //dtRandomRows = dt.Clone();
            Random rDom = new Random();
            int i = 0;
            for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= dt.Rows.Count; ctr++)
            {
               i = rDom.Next(1, dt.Rows.Count);
               //dtRandomRows.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i]);
                dtRandomRows.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
            }
            dtRandomRows.AcceptChanges();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {

        }

        return dtRandomRows;

    }
```

The code above works, but it randomly selects rows from the entire table of the ControlNumbers (orders) and puts them all into dtRandomRows. However, i just want this to select the 'errPercentage' or rows randomly...any thoughts?

Comment: Use the `using` statement to properly dispose your sql objects, otherwise if an exception occurs, the connection isn't closed (bad). Also, use sql parameters, you're code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Would running your `for` loop from 1 to `dt.Rows.Count * errPercentage` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random();

// Mark every row as not selected yet.
int[] nonSelectedRows = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    nonSelectedRows[i] = 1;

int numSelected = 0;
int numLeft = dt.Rows.Count;
int targetNum = dt.Rows.Count * errPercentage;
while(numSelected < targetNum)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
       // Each record has a 1/numleft chance of getting selected.
       boolean isSelected = rand.Next(numLeft) == 0; 

       // Check to make sure it hasn't already been selected.
       if(isSelected && nonSelectedRows[row] > 0)
       {
           dtRandomRows.ImportRow(dt.Rows[row]);
           nonSelectedRows[row] = -1; // Mark this row as selected.
           numSelected++;
           numLeft--;
       }

       // We've already found enough to match our targetNum.
       if(numSelected >= targetNum)
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works fine it seems so far. However, it is random if it even grabs orders. I want the function to always grab the 'errPercentage' of orders.